# Sublime Text key binding

Tags: sublimetext2

I have modified a key binding in sublime text 2, but it is having no effect.

I want to map ctrl+/ to unfold_all command.

I have put this line into my user key bindings file

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+/"], "command": "unfold_all" }
```

But this binding has taken no effect.

Have I entered the syntax incorrectly? Should I modify in the default bindings file?

Comment: Are there any other entries in your user key bindings file? What are the contents of the *entire* file?

Comment: Does your keyboard layout require any additional keys to be pressed? For instance, on a German keyboard layout, the forward slash is on `Shift`+`7` — and your shortcut didn't have any effect. However, I could press the forward slash on the numeric block and unfolding worked.

Comment: My keyboard is a standard US one. My user preferences is the following..[
 { "keys": ["ctrl+/"], "command": "unfold_all" }
]

Answer (score 1):

Special (non-alphanumeric) keys are named, and as it happens the `/` character is named `forward_slash`. So, the following should work:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+forward_slash"], "command": "unfold_all" }
```

Comment: That did not work, but I forgot to add that I am trying to bind to the '/' on top of the number pad, not the one next to the shift key.

Comment: @user3321579 Oh, that makes a difference. In that case, use `keypad_divide`. You can find the (mostly) full list [here](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/key_bindings.html#bindable-keys).